# existential types

Tags: scala, existential-type

(UPDATE: simplified the code and also show why it should work)

How can I fix this code?:

```
case class Sub[B <: Seq[_] : Manifest](b: B) {
  def foo[B2 >: B <: Seq[_] : Manifest](other: Sub[B2]) : B2 =  {
    println(manifest[B])
    println(manifest[B2])

    // next line doesn't compile 
    // other.b ++ b
    other.b 
  }

}
```

If I uncomment the line `other.b ++ b` I get the error:

```
<console>:13: error: Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type Any based on a collection of type Repr.
           other.b ++ b
                   ^
```

If I comment, the code compiles and running it:

```
scala> Sub(List(1,2)).foo(Sub(Seq(4,5)))
scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
scala.collection.Seq[Int]
res0: Seq[Int] = List(4, 5)
```

So the compiler knows that the elements are of type `List[Int]` and `Seq[Int]`. It should have no problem concatenating them.

Note: I want to retain the use of 'B2 >: B' as I need it to be inferred.

Comment: The error message is referring to types "That" and "Repr". Where are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not tied to using an existential type, this should work:

```
case class Sub[T, B[X] <: Seq[X]](b: B[T]) {
  def foo[B2[X] <: Seq[X]](other: Sub[T,B2]) =
     other.b ++ b
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this, although it doesn't solve my real problem since it solves the question (in my original code, there was also inheritance issues that caused 'T' to be inferred as Nothing when using Sub(List(1))).

Comment: Note:  This type: B[X] <: Seq[X] *mandates* that the collection be higher kinded.  I could not use this type:   Foo extends Seq[Int] {} without hacking in a type GoodFoo[X] = Foo.

Answer (score 4):

You've lost the types of Seq[_] by this point, so the only possible B you can get is Seq[Any]...    As such, you can ascribe b to Seq[Any] safely (b : Seq[Any]) ++ b2.

Just because you retained B in B <: Seq[_] does not mean that you can recover the existential type from the sequence.

Comment: +1, but it should read "... you can ascribe Seq[Any] to b: `(b: Seq[Any]) ++ b2`."

Comment: Well, B2 is a concrete type of some Seq, so the compiler should know the element types... And besides, I know the problem, what is the solution? Tried [X, B2[X] <: Seq[X]], but then type inference doesn't work (infers Nothing for X)

Comment: see my updated question. the compiler knows perfectly well the exact types

Comment: @IttayD The B type might hold all the information *but* you've lost the ability to infer anything about the type parameter of Seq due to the existential.  The compiler is unable to *prove* things at runtime because the most it knows about B is that it subclasses Seq[A] forSome { type A }, and *it has no information about the existential type A*

Comment: @IttayD `[X, B2[X] <: Seq[X]]` doesn't mean what you probably expect.  It's equivalent to `[X, B2[Y] <: Seq[Y]]`.